# RavenDb cant create DocumentStore when embedded is installed.

Tags: c#, ravendb

Im want to have a embedded inmemory Db for running quick integration tests. 
So I installed the embedded package from Nuget and everything seemed fine, but when I create my normal documentstore I get a FileNotFoundException and the file is called sparrow.

It works again if I uninstalled the embedded package and clean the solution and rebuild.

The embedded is installed in the project Im calling my server from.
Is not just possible to call an outside server from a project where you have the emedded installed?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you configure the documentstore to run InMemory ?

Comment: Yup. 
But its not the embedded that has problems. Its the remote server.

Comment: I don't get it. You've some sort of server that should host the database (inmemory) and a client application that accesses the database? when you want to connect to you own server from a remote application, you've to enable the HttpServer on the store and use the normal raven client to connect to it

Comment: Ok, so I have a perfectly running (connectable) ravendb remote server datalayer. 
I want to add an embedded inmemory server to be able to do integration tests faster. 
So I add the embedded package from nuget to the datalayer project and now the remote code stops working with the exception in question. The embedded works fine though.

Comment: So you're adding embedded and the client package on the project?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. Is this not allowed (might not be advisable, but is it even supported?)
I realize now that when I've done this before I've placed the embedded documentstore implementation in a separate project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `new EmbeddableDocumentStore`